# Запуск сетевого сервера для разработки проекта

Tags: node.js, angularjs

Как запустить проект так чтоб была возможность просмотра на других ПК? Используя для просмотра страницы ip и порт на котором был запущен проект (http://192.168.1.2:4200/)

Comment: Адрес локальный, могут смотреть только в Вашей сети. Поднять любой  сервер, узнать внутренний IP и заработает. Для доступа из интернета надо поднять что-то вроде [NGrok](https://ngrok.com/).

Comment: А для просмотра по локальной сети, запуск проекта происходит так же через ng serve --open?

Comment: Должен. Я между устройствами через `webpack-dev-server` передаю, `ng serve` делает аналогично.

Comment: просто я когда ввожу для просмотра внутренний ip и порт на котором был запущен проект, то нечего не работает